# LUIS clothing entity

Tags: entity, artificial-intelligence, bots, azure-language-understanding

Within LUIS I want to create an entity for supported clothing/accessories.

I am thinking a Hierarchy entity with children of type Accessory and Outerwear. This will work for my needs, however, I need to exclude items from the entity (non-supported types of clothing).

What is the best approach to exclude items

Comment: Which kind of items? Excluding different accessories and outerwear, excluding inner wear, excluding items not related to clothing at all? What does your current entities look like: Clothing, Clothing::Accessory and Clothing::OuterWear?

Comment: Currently the entity structure is ApparelItem::Accesory and ApparelItem::Outerwear, so umbrella would fall into accessory child, and jacket would fall into outerwear. Now if the model is trained, it'll learn that watch would be an accessory, however, it would have no bearing in the application, and therefore, should not match. Or, do I have to handle his within code, cause all clothing and accessories would be classified within the model. So that in code, I have yo check the entities to see if they are supported, then handle or exclude.

Comment: If you don't plan on working with watches, then you should not train your model to include them. `'ApparelItem::Accessory'` starts off as a blank slate, so just train it with the items relevant to your model and chatbot and exclude words such as watch/watches

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if it would pick up additional items automatically based off of a certain natural pattern. Will see how this goes. Thanks!